# View Double Variable In Memory

Tags: c++, memory, double, cheat-engine

I'm studing about how programs save data on their memory.
So I made a simple program that contains a global double variable :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

double b = 512;

int main(){
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

when I want to search for this double variable in memory from any programs that read memory (in my case CheatEngine), I see something unclear.

CheatEngine Finds the 512 in memory :

[image: 1st Picture]

When I convert it to hex it shows :

[image: 2nd Picture]

And when I browse the location of this variable in memory , It is like :

[image: 3rd Picture]

So I convert 512 from decimal to hex and it is 200, But there is nothing similar 200 in the second picture.

What is 4080000000000000 in the second picture and how it is equal to 512 ?

Comment: Completely unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: double types are encoded using IEEE standard, not integer.

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Answer (score 9):

4080000000000000 is the double representation of +512.0. double are represented with a sign, an exponent and a mantissa in memory.

```
       4   0   8         0     00       00       00       00       00        00
 0    100 00001000     0000 00000000 00000000 0000000 000000000 00000000 00000000
 ^    ------------     ----------------------------------------------------------
 |        
sign  exponent = 2^9   mantissa with implicit high bit = 1 (normal)
```

So the represented number is 2^9 * 1.0 = 512.0.

**Note**

- (408)<sub>16</sub> = 1032
- exponent = 2^(1032 - 1023) = 2^9, where 1023 is the exponent bias

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jean-Francoise, Integer and [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) number representation in memory are different.

A `double` datatype is a 64-bit wide floating point number, meanwhile `0x200` is the integer representation of 512.

You can also use `GDB` to inspect the memory contents of your program, providing you enable debug information to be included in your program.