# why new numbers appear at the end of double variable?

Tags: c, double

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double Mul(double X,double Y,double Z)
{
    Y=Y*pow(10,6);
    Y=Y+Z;
    X=(X*pow(10,12))+Y;
    //X=114360000000000000+117239051145;
    //X=Y;
    
    return X;
}

int main()
{
    double Hello=Mul(114360,117239,511432);
    printf("%f",Hello);

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be "114360117239511432" but I got "114360117239511424" I need to know why 511432 converts to 511424? and How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thank you, But I don't think so. All of my numbers are integer,s not a floating ones.

Comment: Double is a double precision floating point value, not an integer

Comment: Thanks I know, I want to know how to save a 48bit variable into a variable as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to get familiar with [floating point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?noredirect=1&lq=1). However you use decimal numbers as parameters, they are not integers. If you want to know more of the integer limits, please [check the numeric limits](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/).

Let me be more specific. Double type become inaccurate if the exponent other than 1.  I modified a bit your code, to show what are the exact values.

```
double Mul(double X, double Y, double Z)
{
    double YbutMore = Y * pow(10, 6);
    // YbutMore = 117239000000.00000

    double YandZ = YbutMore + Z;
    // YandZ = 117239511432.00000

    double Xpow12 = X * pow(10, 12);
    // Xpow12 = 1.1436000000000000e+17

    return Xpow12 + Y;
    // returns 1.1436000000011723e+17
}
```

So it all begins when we do a `X * pow(10, 12)`. The mantissa cannot hold this big number, so the exponent will be other than `1` that will cause the inaccuracy. Don't forget to check the [double value memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840509/14583599).

If you are intrested how to store accurate and large numbers, please see [How to store extremely large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060242/how-to-store-extremely-large-numbers)

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I've changed the datatype to uint64_t( instead of double) and the accuracy is the same as the last code. Is there any way to compensate the effect of X * pow(10, 12)?

Comment: @JohnJin, `pow` works by using doubles, even when giving it integer arguments. What you need is a power function that does its calculation using `uint64_t`. There should be a lot of implementations out there if you are willing to search the net.